# How to upload jar using `dbms_java.loadjava` from remote system in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, loadjava

I need to upload a jar file in the Oracle database using `dbms_java.loadjava` from a remote system.

I have tried 
`call dbms_java.loadjava('–proxy -Dhttp.proxyHost=remote_system_ip -Dhttp.proxyPort=22 file:///home/abc.jar');`

Its returning `Call completed.` However, while functions in the jar using PLSLQ getting below error.

```
ORA-29540: class com/pkg_name/class_name does not exist
29540. 00000 -  "class %s does not exist"  
*Cause:    Java method execution failed to find a class with the indicated name.
*Action:   Correct the name or add the missing Java class.
```

However, when uploading jar to the Oracle Database server and do the same through using `loadjava` command its working fine.

`loadjava -user dbuser/dbpass path_to_jar/abc.jar`

Then I am able to access the functions in the jar file from my PLSQL code.

Also, one more thing I noted when running `dbms_java.loadjava` it's getting completed successfully for below command even when `abc1.jar` is not a valid file name and doesn't exist.

`call dbms_java.loadjava('–proxy -Dhttp.proxyHost=remote_system_ip -Dhttp.proxyPort=22 file:///home/abc1.jar');`

Please suggest.

Comment: did you get a solution about loadjava?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can only upload from the database server.

The reason why dbms_java.loadjava completes even though the file does not exist: ask Oracle.

But you can always verify using the Oracle dictionary e.g. USER_OBJECTS.